# how to get absolute path for a image in drupal?

Tags: drupal, absolute-path

I have some images in drupal/sites/default/files/images/.

How can I get the absolute path for an image like abc.jpg placed in this directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If Drupal is on its own domain (i.e., `http://example.com`), the absolute path would be `/sites/default/files/images/abc.jpg`.

If Drupal is in a subfolder (e.g. `http://example.com/drupal`), the absolute path would be `/drupal/sites/default/files/images/abc.jpg`.

---

As I explained in my answer on the same question you deleted, if you are trying to programmatically generate the path (that is, you do not know where the file directory is), you need to use [`file_directory_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/file_directory_path/6):

```
$image = file_directory_path() . "/images/abc.jpg";
```

So if the  files are in:

- *sites/default/files*: `$image = "sites/default/files/images/abc.jpg"`.
- *sites/example.com/files*: `$image  = "sites/example.com/files/images/abc.jpg"`.

---

Assuming your previous question is still the use-case, you should be using [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/l) and [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_image/6) to generate the links and images, respectively, within your module. This will ensure the paths generated are correct given Drupal's environment.

Using the expected output you provided before, a solution would be:

```
// Images are in drupalroot/sites/default/files/images
$path = file_directory_path() . '/images/';

$detail_file = 'detail_1.jpg';
$image_file  = '1.jpg';

$img = theme('image', $path . $image_file);

$options = array(
  'attributes' => array(
    'title' => t('Sample title for image 1 lorem ipsum'),
  ),
  'html' => TRUE,
);
$output = l($img, $path . $detail_file, $options);
```

So, assuming your site is at `http://example.com/`, the output would be:

```
<a href="/sites/default/files/images/default_1.jpg" title="Sample title for image 1 lorem ipsum">
  <img src="/sites/default/files/images/1.jpg" height="<image height>" width="<image width>" />
</a>
```

But if your site was in a subfolder (e.g. `http://example.com/drupal`), the output would be:

```
<a href="/drupal/sites/default/files/images/default_1.jpg" title="Sample title for image 1 lorem ipsum">
  <img src="/drupal/sites/default/files/images/1.jpg" height="<image height>" width="<image width>" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 12):

For Drupal 7

```
$relativePath = "blabla/abc.jpg";

$uri = file_build_uri($relativePath);

//show public://blabla/abc.jpg
echo $uri; 

$url = file_create_url($uri);

//show http://www.yoursite.com/sites/default/files/blabla/abc.jpg
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use

```
$url_image = url('sites/default/files/'.file_uri_target($uri), array('absolute'=>true));
```

In that case you will have a path like "http://www.mywebsite.com/sites/default/files/images/image.jpeg"

$uri is an internal path, like "public://images/image.jpeg"

This is Drupal 7, enjoy it, love it

Answer (score 3):

file_directory_path has been removed in drupal 7. If you use it, you'll get an error 'call to undefined function.' Try to use drupal_real_path or . You can find about the deprecated function here. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_directory_path/6

Answer (score 2):

`public://` will give you the absolute path of the public folder

Example: to access

```
drupal/sites/default/files/images/
```

just put

```
public://images/
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried mark's solution and found out that my directory is
"/sites/default/files/images/a.jpg"

But when i write this into my nodes as img src, it didn't show related images.
Besides when i wrote
"../sites/default/files/images/a.jpg"
It worked :)

Because in first case, Drupal tried to find the file in
"content/sites/default/files/images/a.jpg"